# Eclipse cannot find groovy class for Spock/Junit test

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit4, spock

I am working on using spock in eclipse, and when trying to run tests I had successfully run in intelliJ I came across an issue. I had named my class different then my file name and so eclipse is unable to run a junit test and instead gives this error:
[image]
"The Input type of the launch configuration does not exist."

After some googling I got no where and decided to play around and found that if I executed all the test it would run fine, and even when I changed the class name to match the filename it would work. Is there a way to configure eclipse/junit to be able to run a test on a groovy class that does not match the file name?

HelloWorld.groovy:

```
import spock.lang.*

class MyFirstSpockTest extends spock.lang.Specification {

def "length of Spock's and his friends' names"() {
    expect:
    name.size() == length

    where:
    name     | length
    "Spock"  | 5
    "Kirk"   | 4
    "Scotty" | 6
}

def "basic test"() {
    expect:
    Math.min(a, b) == c

    where:
    a | b || c
    3 | 7 || 7   // Will fail here
    5 | 4 || 4   // Will pass
    9 | 9 || 9   // Will pass
}

def "persons name tells you gender"() {
    expect:
    person.getGender() == gender

    where:
    person                    || gender
    new Person(name: "Fred")  || "Male"
    new Person(name: "Wilma") || "Female"
}

static class Person {
    String name

    String getGender() {
        name.equals("Fred") ? "Male" : "Female"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. It's against every convention.

Comment: .... I don't remember asking if I should do this or the convention, but... thanks? I mean the fact that I can't do this might hint at a potential configuration issue but thank god you confirmed the most logical conclusion about a tech I'm obviously learning and playing with.

Comment: Well, the problem sits in front of the computer. So whether you have been asking for it or not, I strongly suggest to follow the advice @chrylis gave you.

Comment: @kriegaex fair enough, my reaction was a little strong, I just find that advice incredibly unhelpful. Now the fact is that my eclipse is not correctly support a basic feature of groovy. Does that sound like that my issue is simply that I am not following naming conventions?

Comment: IMO Eclipse is crap anyway. I only use it because it has good AspectJ support. In all other cases I prefer IDEA. I cannot even get Groovy support working in Eclipse Oxygen, and everytime I want to install updates in Eclipse there is some conflict, resulting in no updates ever getting installed. It has been like this with Eclipse since the earliest days and still persists. Shame on the Eclipse platform developers. The OSGi plugin concept might be nice in theory, but in practice the marketplace never contains the latest versions of anything and other repositories conflict with it.

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment, I unfortunately need to figure out how to work with eclipse. While the convention makes sense, and will likely be a rule for my team, if I am doing something wrong I would like to know before it becomes a real issue.... though maybe then it will be easier to google.

Answer (score 0):

The root of both your main code tree and test code tree need to be in the classpath settings.  To do this, in the Package Explorer window, right click on the Project name, select "Build Path" from the menu, then select "Configure Build Path", select the Source tab and make sure both your main code and test code directories are listed.  If the test code directory is not listed, add it.